# Why does Rust treat '{{' and '}}' differently?

Tags: rust

Because of [escaping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#escaping), I thought that given this code:

```rs
fn main() {
    println!("{}}");
    println!("{{}");
}
```

I would get an error message similar to `unmatched '}' in format string` for the first `println!` and `unmatched '{' in format string` for the second `println!`. However, I *actually* get the same error for both uses of `println!`:

```
error: invalid format string: unmatched `}` found
 --> src/main.rs:2:17
  |
2 |     println!("{}}");
  |                 ^ unmatched `}` in format string
  |
  = note: if you intended to print `}`, you can escape it using `}}`

error: invalid format string: unmatched `}` found
 --> src/main.rs:3:17
  |
3 |     println!("{{}");
  |                 ^ unmatched `}` in format string
  |
  = note: if you intended to print `}`, you can escape it using `}}`
```

This would imply that the first `println!` must take a format argument, and the second doesn't. Why this behavior?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f2eca8cd425abb721ecf6f32c19f18d5)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because this is a formatter string, not just any string, so both `{` and `}` are significant.

Note the escaping notation used here: `{{` is equal to `{`, so `}` on its own is a close without a corresponding open.

In the first case you have *open*, *close*, *close*, so the second close is unmatched.

In the second case you have *literal `{`*, *close*, and the first close is unmatched.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply due to how Rust parses the format string, from left to right. `{}}` parses `{`, which calls for a `}` which is found. Then it goes to `}`, and reports an error. Similarly, with `{{}`, `{` calls for either a `{` (escaped `{`) or a `}`. It finds it, then goes to the next character, `}`, and then reports an error. In both cases, the error is due to the last `}`.